# Storing aggregated total as variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, aggregate-functions

For my report I need to take the Total Sales subtracted by the Cost to get the profit. 
With all the different expressions I have tried, I haven't had any luck.

To find the Total Sales I multiply the Weight times the Unit Cost .
Example: 
`[IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost]`

```
Total Weight = 1,000
Unit Cost = 3
Total Sales = 3,000
```

I need to find out how to store the Total Sales as a variable and then be able to use it later as an expression such as:

```
 Max(@TotalSalesVariable - (@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight) AS [Profit]
```

Currently I am using the expression:

```
AVG([ICP].[UnitCost]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ARC].[CustomerCode])
* SUM(Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])) 
OVER (PARTITION BY [ARC].[CustomerCode])
-  ( @PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS ) * @InputWeight
```

But that does not work because the `AVG` unit cost does not produce the correct number. So I am beginning to think I can only calculate the Profit if I use a variable to store the Total Sales amount.

**Catch, the variable cannot include a `WHERE` statement because the `WHERE` is determined by user input at the time of running the report.**

I am using Microsoft SQL Sever 2005

My full code is posted below:
I updated it after the comment implementing @CostOfSales

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @PurchaseCost Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @InputWeight Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Prod_CostLBS Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @CostOfSales Decimal(19,8);

SET @PurchaseCost = 2.58;
SET @InputWeight = 18100;
SET @Prod_CostLBS  = .15;
SET @CostOfSales  = (@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight;

SELECT 
     CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40)) AS [Supplier]
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , Count(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Alt) AS [Boxes]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , Sum(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Stk) AS [Weight]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost AS [Unit Cost]
   , Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost]) AS [Total Sales]
   , Avg(([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / [IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Alt])) AS [Avg. Box Weight]
   , Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / @InputWeight) AS [Yield]
   , @InputWeight - SUM(Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])) OVER () AS [Shrink]
   , Max((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight) AS [Cost]
   , SUM([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] * [ICP].[UnitCost]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ARC].[CustomerCode]) - @CostOfSales AS [Profit]
   , @CostOfSales AS [CostOfSales]
 FROM (((( IC_Products [PC] 
    INNER JOIN  DC_Transactions [DCT] 
     ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey)
    INNER JOIN  AR_Customers [ARC] 
     ON [DCT].CustomerKey = [ARC].CustomerKey)
    INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots 
     ON [DCT].LotKey = IC_ProductLots.LotKey)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
     ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5)
 WHERE 
    (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' }   AND (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1)  AND [ARC].CustomerKey IN (124) ) 
 GROUP BY 
     CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40))
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost
   , IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate
   , [ARC].CustomerKey
   , [ARC].CustomerCode
 ORDER BY 
     CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40)) 
   , @InputWeight - SUM(Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])) OVER () 
   , Max((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight) 
   , SUM([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] * [ICP].[UnitCost]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ARC].[CustomerCode]) - @CostOfSales
```

Comment: Instead of a variable, why not just `([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost]) - [CostOfSale]`?

Comment: @TabAlleman I like where your head is at. The only problem is that I would need it to take the total for the whole report, not each column. I tried adding SUM and OVER but get the error "Column 'IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Stk' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." I updated my full code above.

Comment: I'm leery of attempting to use windows functions involving (PARTITION BY) in a query that already has a GROUP BY clause.  If you can't write a solution that uses only the GROUP BY, I would put the part that requires PARTITION BY in a cte that does not itself have a GROUP BY.

Comment: @TabAlleman I have used PARTITION BY before while also having a GROUP BY and it has worked fine and correctly. I'm not sure how to create a CTE. I will look into that.